# TTPhotoViewController resize after rotate

Tags: ios, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

when I push a TTPhotoViewController (three20), I got this result :
http://twitpic.com/a4vr5f

then, I rotate the device and get :
http://twitpic.com/a4vra5

Is someone knows why three20 doesn't resize the picture to get a full screen landscape? and how to fix it?

thanks

---edit---

the links for the pictures were reversed

Answer (score 0):

Because three20 preserves your picture's proportions. What is the size of your picture?

Comment: the picture size is determined by three20 as I only give a picture URL to three20, but I know it is big enough to fit the screen width in landscape as I override the ttphotoviewcontroller orientation to landscape in one of my tests. 
so I know three20 keeps the proportions of my picture (and that's what I want), but I also know my picture is large enough to fit all the screen width in landscape, and I should have black bars to fill uncovered space only on the height.it seems like the only transformation applied at rotate time is a pi/2  translation, and no image resize.